# Is posible to change a connection string on a clickonce application without recompile the code

Tags: clickonce

I have many application that are published using clickonce (created using .net framework).

I believe that if I change the appName.config.deploy of the last version of the application, and re-sign the .application file using the MageUI.exe tool, is supposed to update the client. But this is not happening.

Is there a possibility to force the client update the configuration file when the user starts the application?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't change some file without application version changes and have update effect for your clients. Best way is application version increment. We are use 4th octet 1.1.1.X for minor manual updates like you have.

Anyway you can change your "Application name", and for your Client ClickOnce engine your application will be a new one. So the client will have a second shortcut for your application then, if it's okey then here is a steps how to change it:

1. Download utility from second [download link](http://www.devowl.net/2017/04/Alternative-Mage-UI-Sozdanie-ClickOnce-prilozheniya.html)
2. [Choose] your application folder -> [Update] action -> Add any prefix for [Application instance name] field value (for example "_1") -> [Build] + [OK]
3. Resign again